# Radio button in content editable div to mysql with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, contenteditable

I'm using an editablecontent div with some radio button inside it, then i send the result to mysql with an ajax request.

```
<div class="big_wrapper" style="box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19); padding: 10px;" contenteditable>

-----------------------TEXT HERE-------------------------
-----------------------TEXT HERE-------------------------
-----------------------TEXT HERE-------------------------

<input type="radio" name="r1" value="choice 1" /> Choice 1

<br><br>
-----------------------TEXT HERE-------------------------

<input type="radio" name="r1" value="choice 2" /> Choice 2

<br><br>
-----------------------TEXT HERE-------------------------

<input type="radio" name="r1" value="choice 3" /> Choice 3

<br><br>
-----------------------TEXT HERE-------------------------

</div>

-----------------------TEXT HERE-------------------------
-----------------------TEXT HERE-------------------------
-----------------------TEXT HERE-------------------------

<button class="btn btn-blue btn-effect" type="button" id="mybutt">Envoyer</button>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#mybutt').click(function(){
    var myTxt = $('.big_wrapper').html();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url:  '/sent_data.php',
        data: 'q1=' +myTxt+ ''
  });
});
</script>
```

It's correctly sended to mysql, except the choice of one of the three radio button, it doesn't record correctly in mysql => the checked="checked" is not recorded.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't the radio buttons be outside the `contenteditable` div?

Comment: Hello, no i need this inside because i store the ENTIRE result within the <div class="big_wrapper"></div>, with the radio button checked or not.

Comment: I edit my post with some "TEXT", i need to save all the content with TEXT values + the input chosen.

Comment: Any help will be really appreciated ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the content of the `contenteditable` element is treated as *text*, and it seems unlikely you'll be able to get it to act like a form input.  If you search here on SO you will find plenty of other questions asking how to allow HTML inside a `contenteditable` element, here's an example: [HTML Elements inside Contenteditable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41433796/6089612)  The answers show that indeed the content is plain text, and you will need to parse it and convert HTML entites to actually change it into HTML.  So unless you do that, your form inputs aren't going to act like actual form inputs, and the selected value definitely won't be available.  Maybe that's an option for you, but it does not seem like a good solution to me.

It isn't clear *why* you want the radio buttons inside the `contenteditable` element, but a simple and obvious alternative would be to split them up.  You can have either one or multiple `contenteditable`s, and your radio buttons will be real radio buttons, so you can easily find the selected option.  You simply collect up the results to send on button click.

Working example below.  The `POST` data `sent_data.php` will receive will look like this:

```
_POST: Array
(
    [texts] => Array
        (
            [0] => text a
            [1] => more text b
            [2] => last text c
        )

    [value] => choice 2
)
```

If you need to combine that into a single text, you can process it on the back end in PHP (or on the front end in JS of course).

```js
$('#mybutt').click(function () {

    // We will save all texts in an array
    let texts = [];
    let $textFields = $('.big_wrapper');
    $textFields.each(function (i) {
        texts[i] = $(this).html();
    });

    // Now get the single radio value
    let value = $('input[name="r1"]:checked').val();

    // POST away, combining results;
    /*
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/sent_data.php',
        data: {
            'texts': texts,
            'value': value
        }
    });
    */
    
    // For SO show results on console
    let data = {
        'texts': texts,
        'value': value
    };
    console.dir(data);
});
```

```css
.big_wrapper {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="big_wrapper" contenteditable></div>
<input type="radio" name="r1" value="choice 1" /> Choice 1

<br><br><div class="big_wrapper" contenteditable></div>
<input type="radio" name="r1" value="choice 2" /> Choice 2

<br><br><div class="big_wrapper" contenteditable></div>
<input type="radio" name="r1" value="choice 3" /> Choice 3

<br><br><button class="btn btn-blue btn-effect" type="button" id="mybutt">Envoyer</button>
```

Comment: Wow thank you a lot for your great alternative ! :-) Yes it wasn't clear why i want the radio buttons inside the contenteditable but i tried anyway, i thought it was possible. Now i know it's not possible with contenteditable elements, i just need to use soem form elements (i know how to achieve it). Once again thank you